# Kummer congruences for totally real number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, zeta-functions, p-adic-numbers

There is a generalization of the Kummer congruences to totally real number fields with characters due to Deligne-Ribet. For example, see the exposition [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ribet/Articles/luminy.pdf), more precisely see Theorem 2.1.

What is confusing me is that they don't seem to use the L-functions with the Euler factor at p removed (which I will call the p-adic L function) but I thought that the Kummer congruences only held for the p-adic L functions. For instance, for the case of Dirichlet characters, I have only seen the theorem stated for p-adic L functions, for instance see Theorem 2.2 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/DarmonCM/2011Notes/dirichlet.pdf). See also the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_congruence) for Kummer congruences without a character but with a higher order congruence.

Conceptually, I thought of the Kummer congruences as equivalent to the continuity of the p-adic L function but I don't believe the L-function without the p Euler factor removed is continuous.

What am I missing? Is it true that the Kummer congruences (even in the case of just Dirichlet characters) or am I misinterpreting the Deligne-Ribet result?

Comment: You are right in saying that continuity of $L$-functions corresponds to Kummer congruences, and indeed what Deligne--Ribet do is to remove the factors at $p$, as you imagine. Indeed, Theorem 2.1 in Ribet's paper says that the sum of values $\Delta_c(1-k\varepsilon_k)$ is integral: and, one page before, he defines $\Delta_c$ and observes that $\Delta_c(1-k,\varepsilon)=(1-\varepsilon(c)\mathbf{N}(c)^k)L(1-k,\varepsilon).$

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo why is that equivalent to removing an euler factor? c is different from p and moreover the power of N(c ) in the factor is off by one, no? That factor corresponds to the euler factor of c of L(−k,ε), no?

Comment: you are perfectly right, I was writing nonsense (the ideal $c$ is there only for technical reasons to make the integration against a pseudo-measure meaningful). I have posted in the answer below what, I hope, makes sense in place of my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the point lies in the difference between a *primitive* and *imprimitive* $L$-function. Before entering the details, let me observe that Washington's definition of $p$-adic $L$-functions (as the one found in Washington's *Introduction to Cyclotomic fields*, **Theorem 5.11**) gives the interpolation
$$
L_p(1-n,\chi)=(1-\chi\omega^{-n}(p)p^{n-1})L(1-n,\chi)\qquad n\geq 1
$$
and this is shown to be equivalent to the Kummer congruences that you quote, namely
$$
(1-\chi\omega^{-n}(p)p^{n-1})\frac{B_{\chi\omega^{-n},n}}{n}\equiv (1-\chi\omega^{-m}(p)p^{m-1})\frac{B_{\chi\omega^{-m},m}}{m}\pmod{p^a}
$$
whenever $m\equiv n\pmod{p^{a-1}}$ and $\chi=\omega^r$ is a power of the Teichmüller character. The value $\chi\omega^{-n}(p)=\omega^{r-n}(p)$ is considered, in both statements, as the value of the *primitive* character attached to $\omega^{r-n}$ at $p$, in the following sense (the discussion is taken from Chapter 3 of Washington's book). When $r\not\equiv n\pmod{p-1}$, the character $\omega^{r-n}$ has conductor $p$ and is primitive; the value $\omega^{r-n}(p)$ is $0$, hence the "correction factor" disappears. The interesting part arises when $r\equiv n\pmod{p-1}$, so that $\omega^{r-n}$ is the trivial character of conductor $p$: this is an imprimitive character, whose primitivisation is the trivial character of conductor $1$, whose value at $p$ is $1$: the "correction factor" is there and takes the value $(1-p^{n-1})$. This, as Washington remarks right after his **Theorem 5.11** is the Euler factor at $p$ of the complex $L$-function defined on page 31 of his book ($2^\text{nd}$ edition), where the product runs over *all* primes.

In Deligne--Ribet the situation is different, and so is in Ribet's report that you quote. Indeed, in equation $(1.1)$ of his report he defines the $L$-function of a character $\varepsilon$ on a ray class group $G_\mathfrak{f}$ as a Dirichlet series over all prime-to-$\mathfrak{f}$ integral ideals. In section 4 of the report, he applies this to the limit $G_{\mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{p}^\infty}$. To make the bridge with Washington's situation, take $K=\mathbb{Q}$ as base field, and $\mathfrak{f}=1$. As character, chose $\varepsilon=\omega^{r-n}$ with $r\equiv n\pmod{p-1}$ (since otherwise, as discussed, Washington's and Ribet's expressions coincide). Then the $L$-function considered by Ribet is given by
$$
L(s,\omega^{r-n})=\prod_{\ell\neq p}(1-\omega^{r-n}(\ell)\ell^{-s})^{-1}\qquad\operatorname{Re}(s)>1
$$
because $\omega^{r-n}$ is seen as character on $G=G_{p^\infty}$ of conductor $p$, and the sum defining $L(s,\omega^{r-n})$ is performed only over primes $\ell\neq p$. The corresponding Kummer congruences get modified accordingly.

It might be helpful, to convince yourself of this discussion, to compare the interpolation formula proposed by Washington in **Theorem 5.11** and the one proposed by Ribet in his final section on page 13, in the paragraph preceeding equation $(4.6)$: he claims that $L_p(1-k,\varepsilon)=L(1-k,\varepsilon\omega^{-k})$, showing the difference with Washington's.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is helpful but I need to think through it once more to be sure.

Comment: After thinking it through, I think I understand where I went wrong and also why Deligne-Ribet matches Washington. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, would you know of a reference that does Deligne-Ribet in the case of Dirichlet characters? Washington isn't enough because they don't treat the case of a general conductor I think and I don't know of a published reference for the case of Kummer congruences with conductors of arbitrary conductor.

Comment: You mean the construction of the $p$-adic $L$-function for characters over $\mathbb{Q}$? What do you have in mind when you say that Washington doesn't treat it fully?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. What I am looking for is a reference that proves things like the following: Suppose $\chi_1,\chi_2$ are two Dirichlet characters of the same conductor that are congruent modulo a prime $p$. Then, I would like to show that $L(1-k,\chi_1) \equiv L(1-k,\chi_2)$ for all $k \geq 1$. Does this follow directly from the existence of the p-adic L-function for $\chi_1,\chi_2$ ?

Comment: The answer is yes if you restrict a bit the set of $k$'s, for instance to those prime to both conductors, and may be $p$. Just combine Theorem 4.2 with Proposition 4.1 in Washington, together with the interpolation property of $L_p(s,\chi)$.